# NLog - how to print property value of a subclass

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nlog

I have dotnet core console app with bunch of subclasses of same `BaseClass`. I want to assign a short name/moniker to each subclass lets say `public string Moniker => "A1"` and I would like to print it in log when the subclass or base class call Log.

I dont use any DI. The logger is a static field in a singleton class.

There are couple of other classes which print into the log but arent related to the base class.

```
public static NLog.Logger logger;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make it possible to override the name of the Logger for the BaseClass.

Maybe something like this:

```cs
    class BaseClass
    {
        protected virtual Logger Log { get { return _logger } }
        private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger");
    }
    
    class ExactClass : BaseClass
    {
        protected override Logger Log { get { return _logger } }
        private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger.A1");
    }
```

Then use `${logger}` in the Layout:

```
${level} ${logger} ${message}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-create-Logger-for-sub-classes

Comment: `{ get { _logger } }` is invalid C# syntax

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thank you for noticing. Have updated the code example (and the wiki)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it is impossible, or at least hard, to include variable in log layout configuration.

What I would suggest is to define method which will write custom log:

```
public string Moniker => "A1";

public void LogInfo(string message) => Logger.Info($"{Moniker} {message}");
```